# "Can't subset columns that don't exist. x Column `Years` doesn't exist."

Tags: r, dplyr

I am relatively new to R. and Dyplr but was recommended to try using this method but I am unable to see what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it myself.

```
library("readxl")
library(tidyverse)
library("dplyr")
require(ggplot2)


list_of_years <- (unique(terrorism_data$iyear, incomparables = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE, nmax = NA))
df_list_of_years <- as.data.frame(list_of_years)
list_of_countries <- (unique(terrorism_data$country_txt, incomparables = F, fromLast = F, nmax = NA))

final_data_frame <- 0 
final_data_frame <- as.data.frame(final_data_frame)
country <- 0
country <- as.data.frame(country)

x <- 1
y <- 1
z <- 0
while (x <= length(list_of_countries)){
  country <- data.frame(subset(terrorism_data, terrorism_data$country_txt == list_of_countries[x]))
  y <- 1
  while (y <= length(list_of_years)){
    year <- subset(country['iyear'] == list_of_years[y])
    number_of_years <- sum (year[year == TRUE])
    final_data_frame [y,x] <- number_of_years
    y = y + 1
    y
  }
  x = x + 1
  x
}
final_data_frame[,(length(list_of_countries) + 1)] <- list_of_years
names(final_data_frame)[1:(ncol(final_data_frame)-1)] <- list_of_countries
names(final_data_frame)[ncol(final_data_frame)] <- "Years"
final_data_frame$Years <- as.numeric(final_data_frame$Years)

country_specific <- final_data_frame %>%
  select(list_of_countries) %>%
  gather(key = "Countries", value = "value", -"Years")
```

So the data.frame (final_data_frame) is a list of countries on the Y with years as the last column. And on the X is the frequency.

```
U.S China Japan Year
 1   2      3    1997
 2   3       6   1998
```

is what the dataframe looks like. But when i run that last line of code it gives me

```
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `Years` doesn't exist.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use select, you dismiss all columns, that are not inside the statement, therefore Year is missing for the gather.

A solution would be this

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
# your data.frame
final_data_frame <- data.frame(
    U.S. = c(1,2),
    China = c(2,3),
    Japan = c(3,6),
    Year = c(1997, 1998))
# better use pivot_longer than gather
final_data_frame %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(!Year, names_to = "Country", values_to = "Cases")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this work like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Your code refers to plural `Years`, but your variable name is singular `Year`.